# How to check if the request is from the firebase admin and check if it is verified in firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my django server I am sending fcm notifications using firebase-admin and also creating some documents via my server. Whenever I try to send the notification in my server it gives an error 
"firebase_admin.messaging.ApiCallError: The caller does not have permission",

I think it is due to my firestore security rules. Here is my current security rule in firestore. Is there a way to check if my request is from the admin and is secure?

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && emailVerified();
    }

     match /user/{userId} {
        allow read: if isSignedIn() && emailVerified();
      allow write: if isSignedIn();
    }

    function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
    }

    function emailVerified() {
        return request.auth.token.email_verified
    }

    function isOwner(userId) {
            return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDKs run with administrative privileges, which means they bypass the server-side security rules for the database.

You error is coming from `firebase_admin.messaging`, which is a call to Firebase Cloud Messaging. That call is not affected by your Firestore security rules in any way.

From the error message, is is most likely that you're not passing the FCM server token into the call correctly.

Comment: Thanks, It seems I initialized the wrong project in my app.